# What's the alternative of calling a virtual method inside constructor?

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

I have a class that I want to use as an interface. I want that when I create an object that implements this interface, a method (which is different in each implementation) is called automatically.

Now, I would do this by calling a virtual method from the interface constructor, however I get an error. Then I discovered that's not possible to call a virtual method from constructor.

Then, is there a way to achieve the wanted behavior in an alternative way?

Comment: [Factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)

Comment: Is it possible you're looking for [Factory Design](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/factory_method) here? *edit:* too slow am i

Answer (score 0):

You can call the method from the derived class's constructor.